# What trait can I use for a "fuzzy compare" of numeric types?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a "fuzzy compare" function in Rust.

Here is an example:

```
fn fuzzy_cmp(a: f64, b: f64, tolerance: f64) -> bool {
    a >= b - tolerance && a <= b + tolerance
}
```

I have a problem in transforming it to a generic version. Is there a trait that groups natural and floating point numbers, while allowing to perform arithmetic operations on them? Something like this:

```
fn fuzzy_cmp<T: Numbers>(a: T, b: T, tolerance: T) -> bool {
    a >= b - tolerance && a <= b + tolerance
}
```

I would like to use this function in cases like:

```
fuzzy_cmp(x, 20u64, 5u64)
fuzzy_cmp(y, 20f64, 5f64)
// ... etc
```

I've already tried `Ord` trait, but it doesn't work:

```
28:23 error: binary operation `-` cannot be applied to type `T`
a >= b - tolerance && a <= b + tolerance
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Trait `core::num::Num` seems to be deprecated, so I'm not even trying to use it.

Comment: Note: this seems to be the typical "epsilon" method to compare floating point numbers, however be aware that there is an issue with this method => magnitude variations. An absolute "epsilon" will not work when `a` and `b` are of a significantly higher magnitude, because then `b - epsilon == b` and `b + epsilon == b`. You will not have the issue for integrals, obviously. For floating points, therefore, you might want to investigate *relative* epsilons; that is `abs(a - b) / max(abs(a), abs(b)) < epsilon`, which instead guarantees that `a` and `b` are within N% of each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to specify that T should be a built-in number type, only that it must support the addition, subtraction and comparison traits required by your formula:

```
fn fuzzy_cmp<T: Add<T, T> + Sub<T, T> + PartialOrd>(a: T, b: T, tolerance: T) -> bool {
    a >= b - tolerance && a <= b + tolerance
}
```

Comment: I've just came up with a similar solution. `T: PartialOrd + Add<T,T> + Sub<T,T> + Copy`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the correction. I typed too fast and didn't check through the entirety of OP's use case. Above post has been edited.